# Excluding zeroes in a weighted average within a Calculated Field of a Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, weighted-average

I am trying to create a calculated Weighted Average field in an Excel Pivot Table that does NOT include zeroes in the "Total" average row at the bottom of that specific section. I understand how to make the weighted average, but I cannot figure out how to exclude zeroes. I have changed blanks to nas and back again, and every time they result in zero.

First of all, here is the Pivot Table that I have right now:
[Current Pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrxJN.png)

Notice how the 0s in this column are resulting in an average of 1,397, when really the average there should be 12,719. This is my problem. How do I get THAT field to show me 12,719 instead of 1397?

What I want is the fields that say 0 to show - or be blank, or at the very least not have the 0 be calculated into the Total row.

I even re-wrote this calculated field to give me "na" instead of 0 using the formula here:

```
=if((weighted avg formula)=0,"na",(weight avg formula)
```

This worked and resulted in nas in the pivot, but they were treated as 0s.

My source data has only numbers greater than 0 or "na". I also tried replacing the nas with blanks, and it still results in the same 1397 average.

I also came across this Stack Overflow article which discusses ErrorStrings and that looks like it MIGHT solve my problem, but I have no idea how to implement that PivotTable object property. I'm somewhat familiar with VBA within Excel, but really only on a Macro-writing basis.
[How to add a weighted average in my pivot table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550209/how-to-add-a-weighted-average-in-my-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract the number of cells containing "0" from your divisor. Use the [COUNTIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) macro.

Hope this helps.